# How to cancel the value attached to the previously checked radio button when new one is been press

Tags: java, android

Hey guys please I need help on this.

I have a quiz app where I am parsing questions from xml files. I have thousands of questions coming from different `subject.xml` and `subjectanswer.xml` when parsing. I generated a random variable that picks different questions at random and also the answers are picked along side the questions...

So this is my problem when the answers are picked I want to compare it with the answer the user will select. If the user selects, lets say `A` and `A` corresponds with the answer from the parsed xml I want `sum = sum + 10`. In my radio button lets say user first selects the correct answer -> `sum = sum + 10`. Now if the user change her mind and chose another answer... Sum remains as 10... I want the value attached to the previous already selected radio button to be cancel when another radio button is clicked...

I hope you guys get the problem. Please help me out guys..

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
    switch (arg1) {
    case (R.id.a1):

        if (a1.isChecked())
            if (what.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                sumUp = sumUp + 10;
            }

        break;

    case (R.id.b1):
        if (b1.isChecked())
            if (what.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                sumUp = sumUp + 10;
            }
        break;

    case (R.id.c1):
        if (c1.isChecked())
            if (what.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                sumUp = sumUp + 10;
            }
        break;

    case (R.id.d1):
        if (d1.isChecked())
            if (what.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                sumUp = sumUp + 10;
            }
        break;
    }

    String sumUptoString = Integer.toString(sumUp);
    tv3.setText(sumUptoString);

}
```

The `what` variable is the original answer I parsed out from the `subjectanswer.xml`

Comment: You should check and increment the score only when the user has confirmed her decision.

Comment: Please, first check `if (a1.isChecked())`, `if (b1.isChecked())`, etc statements. They look very suspicious.

Comment: I think you need to go about this slightly differently to make it easier.  The OnCheckedChanged should kick off a method that checks all the answers given so far to determine the total. ie. the total is not a stored variable you increment/decrement it is a value you calculate as and when you need to know it.  If you have a total from previous Activitys/quizs etc. then this should be stored separately from the total from the current list of questions and be added on at the end as necessary.  Hope this makes sense and helps.